# using IC in Matlab

Tags: integrated-circuit, matlab, simulink

I dont understand how to simulate circuits which contains IC's(like lt680xx or  IC 555 timer).is it even possible to use them in matlab simulink?If yes, how can we do it?

Comment: Yes. But you already got that information from "some engineer" dude. So, unclear what you're asking,.

Comment: [The manufacturer certainly thinks so.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/examples/pwm-circuit-using-555-timer.html)

Comment: I did not tell they said to me ,if yes what is the  way to do it?

Comment: Your first sentence has two flaws in it: One, is that you're basing your belief off one (uncertain) source. Two, you're saying that it can simulate almost every system. Why "almost"? What are the limitations? What's preventing you from simulating a 555 timer, etc.?

Comment: KingDuken the purpose of my question was to understand if it is true ,or else I would not even ask, "almost" coz there are still limitations like infinity(just a thought)

Comment: why downvote?it was not even a missleading question,I started to think ,more reputation creates halo effects and vice versa

Comment: It got down votes because this is the kind of thing you ask your favorite search machine.  It got close votes for the same reason.  The link I posted, I found in just a couple of minutes.

Comment: The link you posted proves it can be done ,but doesnt even give a clue to do it,also internet is full of garbage infos ,thats why better to take infos from professionals

Comment: That's why I linked to the **manufacturer's** site showing it can be done.

Comment: @jre just to be clear (as in my answer) THAT is a behavioural model and that is what simulink is great for. if you know hte maths it can do it. If the OP is after modeling an NE555 in simulink, then no because that isn't what simulink is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are conflating systems and circuits

Systems are made of of circuits and some circuits make up systems. That does not mean a simulation package which can simulate any system can simulate any circuit

Simulink is a functional/behavioural simulation toolsuite and as such if the system you are interested in, especially classic s-domain systems, can be realised as such then simulink can be deemed to be complete.

Now whether it can simulate an implementation is a different question and basically it it is domain specific... power systems, hydraulic, thermal, rotational mechanical yes... Specific IC? with its specific behaviour (ie spice model) ... no . Newer versions of Simulink do have a spice-like engine and future releases will be incorporating means to load spice models but only for FET,BJT type devices

HOWEVER... if an IC behaviour can be understood and captured (like the 555 timer as @JRE posted) then its behaviour can be simulated